# Unique regex for first name and last name

Tags: java, regex, string, validation, input

I have a single input where users should enter name and surname. The problem is i need to use checking regEx. There's a list of a requirements:

1. The name should start from Capital Letter (not space)
2. There can't be space stacks
3. It's obligate to support these Name and Surname (all people are able to write theirs first/name). Example:

   ```
   John Smith
   and
   Armirat Bair Hossan
   ```
4. And the last symbol shouldn't be space.

Please help,

ATM i have regex like

```
^\\p{L}\\[p{L} ,.'-]+$
```

but it denies ALL input, which is not good

Thanks for helping me

UPDATE:

```
CORRECT INPUT: 
"John Smith"
"Alberto del Muerto"

INCORRECT
"   John Smith   "
" John Smith"
```

Comment: Add on your question examples of valid and invalid inputs

Comment: Please also share the code you have. I think you can try [`^[\p{Lu}\p{M}][\p{L}\p{M},.'-]+(?: [\p{L}\p{M},.'-]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/hO5tU7/2). Do not forget to double backsklashes

Comment: this could help: https://regex101.com^\\p{L}\\[p{L} ,.'-]+$

Comment: Obligatory cautionary note: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: `Alberto del Muerto` shouldn't be correct given your requirement

Comment: @stribizhev Is it possible to explain ?

Comment: If it works for OP, I will post and explain.

Comment: @stribizhev [a suggestion for the 1st `\pM` and allow 1 letter as first word](https://regex101.com/r/hO5tU7/4). And I think you should post

Comment: @stribzhev Worked for me.... now i'm trying to understand what happens there and thnx for link sharing

Comment: @h3dge: I will post then with explanations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
^[\p{Lu}\p{M}][\p{L}\p{M},.'-]+(?: [\p{L}\p{M},.'-]+)*$
```

or

```
^\p{Lu}\p{M}*+(?:\p{L}\p{M}*+|[,.'-])++(?: (?:\p{L}\p{M}*+|[,.'-])++)*+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO5tU7/2) and [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hO5tU7/5)

Java declaration:

```
if (str.matches("[\\p{Lu}\\p{M}][\\p{L}\\p{M},.'-]+(?: [\\p{L}\\p{M},.'-]+)*")) { ... } 
// or if (str.matches("\\p{Lu}\\p{M}*+(?:\\p{L}\\p{M}*+|[,.'-])++(?: (?:\\p{L}\\p{M}*+|[,.'-])++)*+")) { ... }
```

The first regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string (not necessary with `matches()` method)
- `[\p{Lu}\p{M}]` - 1 Unicode letter (incl. precomposed ones as `\p{M}` matches diacritics and `\p{Lu}` matches any **uppercase** Unicode base letter)
- `[\p{L}\p{M},.'-]+` - matches 1 or more Unicode letters, a `,`, `.`, `'` or `-` (if 1 letter names are valid, replace `+` with `-` at the end here)
- `(?: [\p{L}\p{M},.'-]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - - a space
  - `[\p{L}\p{M},.'-]+` - 1 or more characters that are either Unicode letters or commas, or periods, or apostrophes or `-`.
- `$` - end of string (not necessary with `matches()` method)

NOTE: Sometimes, names contain curly apostrophes, you can add them to the character classes (`[‘’]`).

The 2nd regex is less effecient but is more accurate as it will only match diacritics after base letters. See more about matching Unicode letters at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category):

> To match a letter including any diacritics, use `\p{L}\p{M}*+`.

Comment: I suggested [this in the comment](https://regex101.com/r/hO5tU7/4) because it could match a `\p{M}` and not check for uppercase. E.g: `"\u0300abc"` (which is a decomposed `̀abc`)

Comment: The most elaborate answer.

Comment: @Mariano: I understand, but is it possible for a diacritic to appear at the start of a human name? I do not know if such cases can exist. Ah! It's Java, we can use possessive quantifiers :)

Comment: @stribizhev I don't know, I guess so. But if you don't allow diacritics in the first letter, then there's no point in having a `\p{M}` in the first character class, right?

Comment: I added a second option. It is the same, but uses possessive quantifiers and does not allow diacritics to appear before a base letter.

Comment: Beautifully *unrolled*. Thank you for considering the rare decomposed codepoints thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
^[^- '](?=(?![A-Z]?[A-Z]))(?=(?![a-z]+[A-Z]))(?=(?!.*[A-Z][A-Z]))(?=(?!.*[- '][- ']))[A-Za-z- ']{2,}$
```

There is also an interactive [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/81xsIE/1/) of this pattern available at an external website.

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo: the second `\\` should be in front of `p`.
However even then there is a check missing for a trailing space

```
"^\\p{L}[\\p{L} ,.'-]+$"
```

For a .matches the following would suffice

```
"\\p{L}[\\p{L} ,.'-]*[\\p{L}.]"
```

Names like "del Rey, Hidalgo" do not require an initial capital.

Also I would advise to simply `.trim()` the input; imagine a user regarding at the input being rejected for a spurious blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+(([\s][A-Z])?[a-z]+){1,2}$
```

but use \\ instead \ for java

Comment: Could you explain your variant? I partially cant understand

Comment: ^ - start of string  [A-Z] - first capital letter [a-z]+ - one or more lowercase letters. After  ([\s][A-Z])? - space and capital letter and [a-z]+ - one or more lowercase lettrs. {1,2} - part in brackets can be 1 or 2 times(so name can contain 2 or 3 parts) and $ - end of line

Comment: Thanks for explanation